# Selenium link for image list based on image name or link name

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a menu ribbon that is constructed from

tags, Sub lists are hidden until the upper level list is clicked on. How do I identify the target of this image so that I can click on it?

```
<li class="rbnsel">
    <div class="rbl" href="option/index?lfeCyc=Active">
        <img src="../icn/op.png">
        </img>
        Options
    </div>
```

Selenium IDE doesn't identify the image and link (beyond the higher list item), I have tried:

```
css=rbl:contains('option')
```

and

```
xpath=//span[url()='option/index?lfeCyc=Active']
```

Suggestions of what I should be using to identify the Target would be appreciated.

Edit:

I have added the javascript that triggers the link to be created.. So my Selenium IDE table source is below..

```
<tr>
<td>selectWindow</td>
<td>null</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>link=Publish</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>runScript</td>
<td>var path = $(this).attr('href'); if (e.which == 1 &amp;&amp; !e.ctrlKey) {window.location = getCsBaseUrl() + &quot;/&quot; + path;} else {csNewWindow(path);</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>MouseOver</td>
<td>//div[contains(@class, 'rbl') and text()='Options']</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>//div[contains(@class, 'rbl') and text()='Options']</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

I guess perhaps my sequence or code is wrong, I have tried all possible combinations but no luck.

Comment: It's a <div> tag, why did you use <span> in your xpath expression?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, my bad. //div[contains(@class, 'rbl') and text()='Options'] seems to work, but no success in clicking the link yet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fudged a solution - but just using the open command for the links in question. It is not a standard mouseover, mousedown set of actions however it will do for now ;-)

ie command 'open' and Target:

```
/option/index
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.rbl img"));
```

Then you could do

```
string attr = we.getAttribute("src");
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks @bcar, I am using Selenium IDE, with my novice understanding WebElement is for the WebDriver coding- correct? I have identified that using the following Target entry correctly finds the image I need: //div[contains(@class, 'rbl') and text()='Options'] However mouseOver and click Commands are not sufficient to execute the link, I suspect there is some javascript I have to work around... hmm

Comment: WebElement implies a dom element. You might need the JS driver to click, but if your able to get the webelement with your above xpath then id assume you could click. Can you post updated code

Comment: Hi @bcar, Selenium correctly 'finds' the image, but the click does not seem to work. Might need the JS driver as you suggest.. This is the source from the Selenium IDE table: 

<tr>
 <td>MouseOver</td>
 <td>//div[contains(@class, 'rbl') and text()='Options']</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//div[contains(@class, 'rbl') and text()='Options']</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>